# Iteration Vs. Enumeration

Tags: c++

For iteration, I know there are different types of iterators E.g. Forward, Bidirectional, Random Access that can be used to access items in an array.

For enumeration, I've only heard about enums that can be used to index items. But are there terms called 'enumeration' or enumerator? If so then, What's the difference between iteration and enumeration?

Comment: [enumerator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html) is a java concept that allows you to iterator over a range/container.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The terminology is really tied to the language, and gets pretty confusing.

In C++, *an "enumerat​**ion**"* (`enum`) is a **name**, meaning "a bunch of numbered items", so there's no *action* going on; it's just a *thing* (like a `class`).

And of course, "iterat​**ion**" refers to an *action*, meaning "to repeat an action many times". Often, this is accompanied by going through a list of items.

But, in some languages, each one has a specific meaning as an *action*:

- C#: Enumerators are *objects* that go through the items of a collection (like C++ iterators; `IEnumerator<T>`). Iterators are *methods* that do pretty much the same thing, but in coroutine-style (`yield return`).

  C# still has enumerat​*ion*​s (`enum`s) like in C++.
- Java: Iterators go through the items of a collection, like in C++. I'm not sure about "enumerators".

  Java still has enumerat​*ion*​s similar to C++, but they're sort of different as well.
- Python: Iterators are like C# enumerators; *generators* are like C# iterators (`yield`).

  No enumerat​*ion*​s, AFAIK.

etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the case in c++, but in java an enumerator is essentially a faster iterator since it is not thread safe, and so it doesn't have the overhead due to checks for thread access which is done by an iterator.

See this [blog entry](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDIQFjAB&url=http://javabeanz.wordpress.com/2007/06/29/iterator-vs-enumeration/&rct=j&q=enumerator%20vs%20iterator%20java&ei=KrtaTo73McPy0gHHvdSUCQ&usg=AFQjCNGaFuM6WUcTXkOyNJ6xK3uvPPlkWw) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially C++'s SinglePassIterator, Java's Iterator and C#'s IEnumerator are all equivalent.

AFAIK Java and C# doesn't offer ForwardIterator-like functionality probably because they need to be "cloneable",
which is a heavy operation for virtual machines. Making a new copy into array and index-accessing is much faster than iterators.